# How do I find which versions of ruby, gem and bundler are compatible?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, puppet

I am using puppet to install ruby 1.9.3 as the system ruby on an Ubuntu Trusty Vagrant container. I also install Bundler. I am told that "gem" is installed as part of the installation of ruby.

- How do I know which versions of gem go with this version of ruby?
- How do I know which versions of bundler go with this version of ruby?
- Here is a fragment of puppet code:

  $other_reqs = [
      ...
      'ruby1.9.3',
      'ruby-bundler',
      'rubygems-integration',
      ...
    ]

  package{ $other_reqs: ensure => 'installed'} -> Package['percona-toolkit']

The package declaration will default to using apt-get to download packages. Clearly the line with 'ruby1.9.3' will get the 1.9.3 version of ruby. It also installed gem 1.8.23. Is this a compatible version of gem? How do I know?

The line with 'ruby-bundler' installed Bundler version 1.3.5. Is this a compatible version of Bundler? Or should I indicate a specific version in my requirements array? Where ought I look to find this information?

Answer (score -1):

It might be helpful if you indicate the problem, or what you're trying to do. Nevertheless:

`gem` is a command that is built-in in ruby from 1.9+, so whatever comes installed with Ruby should be fine.

`bunlder` is a RubyGem, normally installed by doing `gem install bundler`. You can specify the version by doing `gem install -v <version>`. Either it gets installed correctly or you get an error. Can you install bundler doing that?

And lastly, unless you need it for a specific reason, 1.9 is very old :)

Comment: Yes, 1.9 is old, but we are upgrading from 1.8.7! I am aware of HOW to specify a version, the question is finding out WHICH version of bundler goes with with 1.9.3. We are installing bundler using apt-get install.

Comment: That's a thing that feels weird for me :) (I'm just not familiar with installing it that way). I guess you can't install bundler doing `gem install bundler` and forget about what's version is valid or not, right?

Comment: Anyhow, does it work if you check bundler gemspec? There it states which ruby version and rubygem versions it needs https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/bundler.gemspec

Comment: I have been instructed to spot check our rails2 application to see if bundle install works and the application continues to come up, which should be an adequate test. And yes, one normally will install bundler using gem install, but in puppet it is so EASY to use apt-get that we are already doing it that way.